# FlutterFlow - The method 'ViewProfileWidget' isn't defined for the type '_CustomWidgetState'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I'm writing the code for a custom widget and I need to navigate to another page (ViewProfileWidget) on a specific condition.
FlutterFlow seems to compile and work in preview/run mode but I still get a compile error:

```
The method 'ViewProfileWidget' isn't defined for the type '_CustomWidgetState'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ViewProfileWidget'.
```

This is the code throwing the error:

```
void _onTap(int profileId) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement<void, void>(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) =>
            ViewProfileWidget(profileJson: {"field" : "value}),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've tried also using

```
Navigator.pushNamed()
```

as I think it would be an equally good solution for me, but the named route is not found for some reason I can't understand

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the file where ViewProfileWidget is defined is not imported in your view. You can try import it :

```dart
import './relative/path/to/your/file.dart';
```

Comment: I really tried in every possible way with every possible path, with no success. The only path suggested by the "autocomplete" in the built-in FlutterFlow editor is `import 'package:my_app_name/pages/view_profile/view_profile_widget.dart';`, but at compile time I get the same error

Comment: Can you provide your pubspec.yaml and your app folder tree within your original post.

Is your dart analyser working and does it show an error at the import line ? Do you use vscode or any IDE beside of Flutter Flow ?